# Modifying Spark RuntimeConfig

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to understand what properties of Spark can be modified *after* the SparkSession has been created, using the RuntimeConfig object (SparkSession.conf).

According to the following article, it is possible to modify the number of executor cores, for example:

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html

However, the same example in the article didn't work for me - setting "spark.executor.memory" in SparkConf before creating the session, and then overriding it after the session object has been created, had no effect - the value that was used in SparkConf is the one that took effect (I also tried with spark.cores.max to the same effect):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("bla").set("spark.cores.max","1")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.cores.max","10") <---- this is ignored!
```

Has anyone been able to modify various Spark runtime configuration, after the session has been created?

p.s. The current behavior that I'm seeing is exactly what I want to happen (I don't want anyone to change the SparkSession config after it's been created), but I want to make sure it is by design.